# Creating clear gel pill having translucency issues

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, transparency, lighting

I am trying to make a clear gel pill capsule and there is this weird wireframe effect as seen in the photo. Is it a result of the lights or do you think its the wireframe mesh? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Also any ideas on how to make the background lighting more compelling is appreciated. I still want it to feel very clean. Thanks for your time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hard to say, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This looks like a case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting.
Does your capsule have an inner section whose outer wall intersects with the inner wall of the outer section? If so, maybe scale the inner section just a bit smaller and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for what will now be a question others may not have, my issue was that I had a mirror modifier on both halves of the pill so I am assuming the problem is similar to the Z-Fighting @haarigertroll shared but not positive. I removed the mirror modifier and the issue is gone. Thanks to all who gave input.